# how to avoid getting several duplicate rows after joining

Tags: join, duplicates

ok, so i have 4 tables:

```
credits, playlog, sessionlog, user
```

`credits` has the column `userid` to join with `user`.
`playlog` has `sessionlogid` to join with `sessionlog`.
`sessionlog` has `userid` to join with `user`.

So when I join anything with `sessionlog`, which I HAVE to do to get the users, rows will be listed multiple times.

I think I know why this happens, I just don't know how to prevent it.

So every time a player plays a level, a `playlog` (and every `playlog` contains the `sessionlogid`) is created.

When I join everything together, every player gets listed as often as he has `playlog`s, although I only want him to be listed once.

When I take a look at credits from a specific player, I get 2 rows for example, depending how often he spent credits.

But as soon as I join that with `sessionlog`, these 2 rows get multiplied it seems with how many `playlog`s belong to that `sessionlog` - if he played 5 levels, these 2 payment-rows get multiplied by 5 and the output is 10 rows for 2 payments.
this is giving me massive problems to calculate the payments-per-level.

How can I make a query that only takes the latest `playlog` from every `sessionlog` plus additional constraints?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you want to query:
1. Credit (log) and display all the credit spend history?
-or-
2. User and display the total Credit?

Comment: as a result i want to have a column with a list of all levels (playlog logs which level was played) and a column that lists how much credit was spent on every level

Comment: You're still not providing enough information.  You should consider putting up some sample data for each table and sample of the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing enough info. Here's an attempt: This will give you a list of USERS and HOW MUCH CREDIT each Spent Per Play:

```
SELECT      dbo.Users.userID
            , dbo.Users.userName
            , SUM(dbo.Credit.CreditChange) AS NetCreditSpent
            , COUNT(dbo.PlayLog.sessionlogid) AS PlayCount
            , 1.0 * SUM(dbo.Credit.CreditChange) / COUNT(dbo.PlayLog.sessionlogid) AS CreditSpentPerPlay
FROM        dbo.Credit
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.PlayLog
                INNER JOIN dbo.SessionLog
                    ON dbo.PlayLog.sessionlogid = dbo.SessionLog.sessionlogid
                RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.Users
                    ON dbo.SessionLog.userid = dbo.Users.userID 
                    ON dbo.Credit.userID = dbo.Users.userID
GROUP BY    dbo.Users.userID, dbo.Users.userName
```